# Choked on a piece of pumpkin

Tags: translation

Welcher Satz ist korrekt? Ich versuche, den englischen Satz „I choked on a piece of pumpkin again“ ins Deutsche zu übersetzen.

1. Wieder habe ich mich an einem Stück Kürbis verschluckt.
2. Wieder habe ich mich an einem Stück Kürbis geschluckt.
3. Wieder habe ich mich an einem Stück Kürbis erstickt.
4. Wieder bin ich an einem Stück Kürbis erstickt.
5. Wieder war ich an einem Stück Kürbis erstickt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nur Satz 1 ist sowohl grammatisch als auch inhaltlich richtig. Allerdings klingt er nicht besonders natürlich.

> **Wieder** habe ich mich an einem Stück Kürbis verschluckt.

Das klingt so, als ob das ein Wettbewerb wäre.

> **Schon wieder** habe ich mich an einem Stück Kürbis verschluckt.

Das ist eine wütende Klage.

> **Mal wieder** habe ich mich an einem Stück Kürbis verschluckt.

Das hingegen ein resignierendes Hinnehmen.

Answer (score 5):

**"Sich verschlucken"** means food got into the respiratory tract instead of the gillet. This normally results in coughing, in more serious cases the person can't breathe any more and needs help (claps, on the back, Heimlich maneuver).

**"Ersticken"** means dying of not enough oxygen. "Wieder ersticken" doesn't make sense since you can only die once.

Your variants have some more differences that go beyond a single question on SE. Please ask about them separately if needed. #1, #4 and #5 are correct German sentences, of which #1 and #4 are translations of the English sentence, but only #1 actually makes sense and is probably what's meant.

Comment: Also, ist der erste Satz fein?

Comment: @TeerseifemögenderMr.Kater keiner Satz ist fein.